# What is the origin of the term "crash hot"?

Tags: etymology, slang

The term "crash hot" is often used in the negative, such as "I'm not feeling too crash hot today". I am trying to find out when the term was first used and why. I have used Internet search but have not found anything about its origin.

Comment: I never heard of ***crash hot*** (as opposed to *"I'm not feeling too **hot** today"*, meaning I'm feeling weak/lethargic). Can you either explain or post a link to something telling us what difference you think adding ***crash*** makes?

Comment: This is indeed my question. Where did the "crash" bit come from? I think Josh's answer below provides some good information. "Extremely" seems to fit.

Comment: I always assumed *crashing bore* was some kind of conflation with ***crushing** bore* (whose ramblings weigh you down), and that a *crash diet* was a *sudden, fast* one (crashes being things that happen *quickly*). The more general extension to *very, extremely* doesn't really strike a chord with me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its usage seems to have been increasing since the 80's/90's mainly in Australia. Its origin is not clear, probably from  'crash' in the sense of  'extreme'.

[Crash hot](http://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/crash_hot) (from wiktionary)

> - (slang, Australia, New Zealand) Very good, excellent; very well.
>     Well well well, don′t you look crash hot in your new sunnies!
>
>   - I'm sorry boss, I can′t come in to work today, I′m not feeling too crash hot.
>       *1991, Antonio Casella, The Sensualist, page 28,*
>       Certainly Nick isn′t too crash hot on the old pen, something which he admits freely.

[Origin:](http://www.yourdictionary.com/crash-hot) (from yourdictionary.com)

> - Perhaps a nonstandard adverbial usage of crash (“extremely”) + hot (“performing well”).

The following extract refers to *crash hot* as a [mid-80s](http://www.surfcampinportugal.com/never-too-old-to-learn-to-surf/) Australian expression:

> - I was young and living in Australia with muscles that worked. My time in Sydney wasn’t all wasted, though: I did buy a pair of Hot Tuna boardshorts – they were crash-hot (authentic mid-80s Aussie slang).

According to The [Dictionary of Contemporary Slang](http://books.google.it/books?id=5He9AgAAQBAJ&pg=PA111&lpg=PA111&dq=crash%20hot%20australian%20slang&source=bl&ots=eZw-4QglKo&sig=h8IjBFKXKaubB9D-Gy06Fo-0oVM&hl=it&sa=X&ei=syNZVP2cIo7napSSgcgL&ved=0CDEQ6AEwBTgK#v=onepage&q&f=false)
 
 di Tony Thorne, the expression might be an euphemism for *shit-hot*.

[Ngran](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=crash%20hot%2C%20crash-hot&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccrash%20hot%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccrash%20-%20hot%3B%2Cc0) crash hot

Comment: Perhaps that ***crash** = extremely* sense is also primarily Australian, which might explain why I've never heard it in the UK. Presumably related to the now-somewhat-dated ***crashing*** most commonly encountered in *"He's such a crashing bore"*.

Comment: A 'crash diet' comes to mind with the meaning of 'extreme'.

Comment: @Josh. Very useful answer +1. I had forgotten how nifty (there is a word that should come back) the ngram viewer can be! I am still hoping someone may know who came up with the term or first used it in the open media.

Comment: It's common to use terms like "smashing" ("smashing time") or "bang" ("bang in the middle") for emphasis, as well "crashing" which has been mentioned, as so this is probably a similar phenomenon.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding growing up in Australia it was a "spannerhead" term, which meant the engine was running hot ready to break down or crash to bits.
Hence, *too crash hot*.